# How do you make an exception to a .htaccess rewrite rule?

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am rewriting using .htaccess to remove ".html" extensions from my website. However, I use the URL in a function to pass a parameter to another page (mysite.com/locations#12345)

My rewrite rules are the following:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

I tried doing this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /locations/([^.]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /locations%1 [NC,L,R]
```

But I get "mysite.com/locations%20HTTP/2#12345"

Comment: What is your original URL and what should be redirected URL?

Comment: I am requesting "mysite.com/locations#12345" but the rewrite rule I use is rewriting it. If I remove my attempt to overwrite, my current rule makes that URL "mysite.com/locations/#12345" - the "/" can't be there because it takes me to the locations/ directory instead of the page.

Comment: Your original rule is only removing `.html` from a URL but you don't have `.html` in `mysite.com/locations#12345`

Comment: Even if I request "mysite.com/locations.html#12345" it gets rewritten to "mysite.com/locations/#12345 - Requesting with or without ".html" produces the same rewrite with the first two conditions.

Comment: If `locations` is a real directory then a trailing slash will be added by `mod_dir` automatically. Do you have a file called `locations.html` and a directory named `locations/`?

Comment: Yes, I have both. Locations directory holds pages, but locations.html page is redirected to when a "# + number" does not correspond to a location. I use the URL to display the entered zip code on the locations.html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to turn off `DirectorySlash` to turn off trailing slash for directories moreover turn off `Indexes` to avoid listing directory content.

```sh
DirectorySlash Off
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^.]+)\.html[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Make sure to test it after clearing browser cache.

Comment: Seems to work! One thing... cursors on my site no longer change to "pointer" on links, the cursor remains default. Kind of a problem for usability. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry that is not related to server side, might be some css styling issue that I am not aware of

Comment: Not sure what was causing it actually, since I made no CSS changes. After about 5 minutes the cursor issue went away. Strange! I will mark your answer as the accepted one. Thank you!